# Haskell Fibonacci sequence performance depending on methodology

Tags: performance, list, haskell

I was trying out different approaches to getting a number at a given index of the Fibonacci sequence and they could basically be divided into two categories:

- building a list and querying an index
- using variables (might be separate or tupled, without a list)

I picked an example of both:

```
fibs1 :: Int -> Integer
fibs1 n = fibs1' !! n
    where fibs1' = 0 : scanl (+) 1 fibs1'

fib2 :: Int -> Integer
fib2 n = fib2' 1 1 n where
    fib2' _ b 2 = b
    fib2' a b n = fib2' b (a + b) (n - 1)
```

fibs1:

```
real    0m2.356s
user    0m2.310s
sys     0m0.030s
```

fibs2:

```
real    0m0.671s
user    0m0.667s
sys     0m0.000s
```

Both were compiled with 64bit GHC 7.6.1 and `-O2 -fllvm`. Their core dumps are very similar in length, but they differ in the parts that I'm not very proficient at interpreting.

I was not surprised that `fibs1` failed for n = 350000 (`Stack space overflow`). However, I am not comfortable with the fact that it used that much memory.

I would like to clear some things up:

1. Why does the GC not take care of the beginning of the list throughout computation even though most of it quickly becomes useless?
2. Why does GHC not optimize the list version to a variable version since only two of its elements are required at once?

EDIT: Sorry, I mixed the speed results, fixed. Two of three of my doubts are still valid, though ;).

Comment: Can't reproduce, `fib2` is much faster than `fibs1` here. How do you run the code?

Comment: Thanks for noticing it. I had a lot of different versions and their naming was not very imaginative ;).

Comment: You should be surprised that `fibs1` stack overflows. The reason it does is the same reason it uses so much memory.

Comment: And this is far from a complete answer, but it's a data point: `scanl' f !y ls = case ls of { [] -> [y] ; (x:xs) -> y : scanl' f (f y x) xs }`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Why does the GC not take care of the beginning of the list throughout computation even though most of it quickly becomes useless?

`fibs1` uses a lot of memory and is slow because `scanl` is lazy, it doesn't evaluate the list elements, so

```
fibs1' = 0 : scanl (+) 1 fibs1'
```

produces

```
0 : scanl (+) 1 (0 : more)
0 : 1 : let f2 = 1+0 in scanl (+) f2 (1 : more')
0 : 1 : let f2 = 1+0 in f2 : let f3 = f2+1 in scanl (+) f3 (f2 : more'')
0 : 1 : let f2 = 1+0 in f2 : let f3 = f2+1 in f3 : let f4 = f3+f2 in scanl (+) f4 (f3 : more''')
```

etc. So you rather quickly get a huge nested thunk. When that thunk is evaluated, it is pushed on the stack, and at some point between 250000 and 350000, it becomes too big for the default stack.

And since each list element holds a reference to the previous while it is not evaluated, the beginning of the list cannot be garbage-collected.

If you use a strict scan,

```
fibs1 :: Int -> Integer
fibs1 n = fibs1' !! n
  where
    fibs1' = 0 : scanl' (+) 1 fibs1'
    scanl' f a (x:xs) = let x' = f a x in x' `seq` (a : scanl' f x' xs)
    scanl' _ a [] = [a]
```

when the `k`-th list cell is produced, its value is already evaluated, so doesn't refer to a previous, hence the list can be garbage collected (assuming nothing else holds a reference to it) as it is traversed.

With that implementation, the list version is about as fast and lean as `fib2` (it needs to allocate list cells nevertheless, so it allocates a small bit more, and is possibly a tiny bit slower therefore, but the difference is minute, since the Fibonacci numbers become so large that the list construction overhead becomes negligible).

The idea of `scanl` is that its result is incrementally consumed, so that the consumption forces the elements and prevents the build-up of large thunks.

> Why does GHC not optimize the list version to a variable version since only two of its elements are required at once?

Its optimiser can't see through the algorithm to determine that. `scanl` is opaque to the compiler, it doesn't know what `scanl` does.

If we take the exact source code for `scanl` (renaming it or hiding `scanl` from the Prelude, I opted for renaming),

```
scans                   :: (b -> a -> b) -> b -> [a] -> [b]
scans f q ls            =  q : (case ls of
                                []   -> []
                                x:xs -> scans f (f q x) xs)
```

and compile the module exporting it (with -O2), and then look at the generated interface file with

```
ghc --show-iface Scan.hi
```

we get (for example, minor differences between compiler versions)

```
Magic: Wanted 33214052,
       got    33214052
Version: Wanted [7, 0, 6, 1],
         got    [7, 0, 6, 1]
Way: Wanted [],
     got    []
interface main:Scan 7061
  interface hash: ef57dac14815e2f1f897b42a007c0c81
  ABI hash: 8cfc8dab79de6a51fcad666f1869574f
  export-list hash: 57d6805e5f0b5f76f0dd8dfb228df988
  orphan hash: 693e9af84d3dfcc71e640e005bdc5e2e
  flag hash: 1e8135cb44ef6dd330f1f56943d1f463
  used TH splices: False
  where
exports:
  Scan.scans
module dependencies:
package dependencies: base* ghc-prim integer-gmp
orphans: base:GHC.Base base:GHC.Float base:GHC.Real
family instance modules:
import  -/  base:Prelude 1cb4b618cf45281dc97748b1831bf0cd
d79ca4e223c0de0a770a3b88a5e67687
  scans :: forall b a. (b -> a -> b) -> b -> [a] -> [b]
    {- Arity: 3, HasNoCafRefs, Strictness: LLL -}
vectorised variables:
vectorised tycons:
vectorised reused tycons:
scalar variables:
scalar tycons:
trusted: safe-inferred
require own pkg trusted: False
```

and see that the interface file doesn't expose the unfolding of the function, only its type, arity, strictness and that it doesn't refer to CAFs.

When a module importing that is compiled, all that the compiler has to go by is the information exposed by the interface file.

Here, there is no information exposed that would allow the compiler to do anything else but emit a call to the function.

If the unfolding were exposed, the compiler had a chance to inline the unfolding and analyse the code knowing the types and combination function to produce more eager code that doesn't build thunks.

The semantics of `scanl`, however, are maximally lazy, each element of the output is emitted before the input list is inspected. That has the consequence that GHC can't make the addition strict, since that would change the result if the list contained any undefined values:

```
scanl (+) 1 [undefined] = 1 : scanl (+) (1 + undefined) [] = 1 : (1 + undefined) : []
```

while

```
scanl' (+) 1 [undefined] = let x' = 1 + undefined in x' `seq` 1 : scanl' (+) x' []
                         = *** Exception: Prelude.undefined
```

One could make a variant

```
scanl'' f b (x:xs) = b `seq` b : scanl'' f (f b x) xs
```

that would produce `1 : *** Exception: Prelude.undefined` for the above input, but any strictness would indeed change the result if the list contained undefined values, so even if the compiler knew the unfolding, it couldn't make the evaluation strict - unless it could prove that there are no undefined values in the list, a fact that is obvious to us, but not the compiler [and I don't think it would be easy to teach a compiler recognize that and be able to prove the absence of undefined values].

Comment: I should have guessed that it was laziness that caused stack overflow. I didn't suspect scanl, though. I guess I am too trusting towards `Prelude` functions. Can you expand on the notion of `scanl` being opaque to the compiler?

Comment: I've added a piece about that. On writing that, I saw that even if it weren't opaque, the compiler cannot make `scanl` strict [well, in some circumstances it could, but discerning these would be a surprising feat].

Comment: Thanks for the extended information; I will have to investigate the interface stuff - there seems to be some magic to it :).